# ArrayAdapter is repeating UI Header for every item in ListView

Tags: android, listview, user-interface, android-arrayadapter

I am facing an issue in showing a list of items in the UI.

My UI layout page layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ListOfRecordsContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#454545"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:layout_weight="1"
        layout="@layout/header" />

    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ListOfRecords"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.01"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:textSize="12sp" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

In the Class, `onSuccess()` method is called once the list is retrieved from a remote system and populate the `TextView` in the UI.

But,the Header part included in the layout is getting repeated for every record. Am I missing anything here??

For instance....Actual result is

```
<Header Button for LogOut>
Item1
<Header Button for LogOut>
Item2
```

Expected Result is

```
<Header Button for LogOut>
Item1
Item2
```

Code is shown below:

---

```
public class ItemMainPage extends ListActivity{

    private String[] AccountName;
    private String[] AccountIds;
    private RestClient client;
    private String apiVersion;

    LinearLayout layout;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ListView lv = getListView();
        apiVersion = getString(R.string.api_version);

        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        /*layout = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.list_item_main_page, null);
        Button buyButton = new Button(this);
        buyButton.setText("Search");
        layout.addView(buyButton);*/


    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        // Login options
        String accountType = getString(R.string.account_type);
        LoginOptions loginOptions = new LoginOptions(
                null, // gets overridden by LoginActivity based on server picked by uuser 
                ForceApp.APP.getPasscodeHash(),
                getString(R.string.oauth_callback_url),
                getString(R.string.oauth_client_id),
                new String[] {"api"});

        new ClientManager(this, accountType, loginOptions).getRestClient(this, new RestClientCallback() {
            //@Override
            public void authenticatedRestClient(RestClient client) {
                if (client == null) {
                    ForceApp.APP.logout(ItemMainPage.this);
                    return;
                }
                ItemMainPage.this.client = client;
                getAccountList();
            }
        });
        EventsObservable.get().notifyEvent(EventType.RenditionComplete);
    }   

    private void getAccountList(){

        try {

            String soql = "select id, name from Account LIMIT 2";
            RestRequest request = RestRequest.getRequestForQuery(apiVersion, soql);

            client.sendAsync(request, new AsyncRequestCallback() {

                //@Override
                public void onSuccess(RestRequest request, RestResponse response) {
                    try {
                        if (response == null || response.asJSONObject() == null)
                            return;

                        JSONArray records = response.asJSONObject().getJSONArray("records");

                        if (records.length() == 0)
                            return;

                        AccountName = new String[records.length()];
                        AccountIds = new String[records.length()];

                        for (int i = 0; i < records.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject Account = (JSONObject)records.get(i);
                            AccountName[i] = Account.getString("Name");
                            AccountIds[i] = Account.getString("Id");
                        }
                        //ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ItemMainPage.this, 
                        //                                                 R.layout.list_item_main_page, 
                        //                                                 AccountName);
                        ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ItemMainPage.this, R.layout.list_item_main_page, R.id.ListOfRecords, AccountName); 
                        setListAdapter(ad);
                        Log.d("Adapter", ad.toString());
                        //EventsObservable.get().notifyEvent(EventType.RenditionComplete);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        displayError(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }

                //@Override
                public void onError(Exception exception) {
                    displayError(exception.getMessage());
                    EventsObservable.get().notifyEvent(EventType.RenditionComplete);
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            displayError(e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    private void displayError(String error) {
        //ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(   AccountList.this, R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"Error retrieving Account data - " + error});
        //setListAdapter(ad);
      ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome_text)).setText(getString(R.string.welcome, client.getClientInfo().username));

    }

}
```

Please help if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the XML you provided is used as the row layout, which means:

```
<include
    android:layout_weight="1"
    layout="@layout/header" />
```

is included in every row (like what you are seeing).

If you want to add a header to your ListView try:

```
View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
listView.addHeaderView(header);
```

and remove the `include` element from the row layout.

Comment: Many Thanks. The solution works, , but say I need to have a search bar        above the list to search for items in the list, and separately, a header for the list...how would that be possible ?

Comment: There are many ways to do this, in fact, here is an entire [Android Developer Article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) on the subject. If you need specific help don't hesitate to ask a new question providing as much detail as you did here.

Answer (score 0):

Make your header a separate XML layout and add to your listview using addHeaderView.  IE:

```
    View header = (View)getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);
    lv.addHeaderView(header);
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Many Thanks. The solution works, , but say I need to have a search bar above the list to search for items in the list, and separately, a header for the list...how would that be possible ?